# A Powerful Mechanical Turk Web Interface

Tags: mechanicalturk, qualtrics

I am trying to run a Mechanical Turk Qualtrics based survey and need some features that seem available through the Mechanical Turk API like [custom Qualifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateQualificationTypeOperation.html) but are not accessible from the [Requester web site](https://requester.mturk.com/).

Are there any third party providers of a web site like this that gives users access to the API without having to learn programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [TurkPrime.com](http://www.turkprime.com) which makes it extremely easy to interact with MTurk's API without any programming knowledge. They even have integration with [Qualtrics surveys](http://blog.turkprime.com/2015/05/qualtrics-surveys-with-turkprime.html) that creates a new secret code for each worker and each assignment can be either manually or automatically approved / rejected.